# Saving template information in Subclass

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a parent-class with a function. In this function I want to call a template method but the type of the template depends on the type of sub-class. So I want to save the information about T there. I can't  call foo with a template because it's from another part of the Program which I can't change

```
class A
{
    //this will be called on an instance of B or C, A will never be 
    //instantiated
    void foo()
    {
        ba<T>();
    }
}


class B :public A
{
//T want to save here the Type of T so i won't have to call foo() with 
//a template
}

class C :public A
{
//here comes another Type for T
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what is `T` here. What is "type of the template" ?

Comment: the definition is
    template<typename T>
    T* ba()
for example i want to call in foo() in class B with ba<int>() can i save the information about this in class B?

Comment: You want like subclass `B` calls `ba<T_of_B>`, and `C` calls `ba<T_of_C>` ?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Comment: Please first edit your question, `public` is not to qualify class, C++ is not java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern, which is very common in C++ template programming.

```
template<class T>
void ba() {}

template<class Derived>
struct A
{
    void foo() {
        ba<typename Derived::MyT>();
    }
};

struct B
    : public A<B>
{
    using MyT = int;
};

struct C
    : public A<C>
{
    using MyT = double;
};


int main() {
    B b;
    b.foo();
    C c;
    c.foo();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a template parameter to the base class A and then specify the type in the declaration of B and C.  See the example below:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    public:
    void foo()
    {
        ba<T>();
    }
};


class B : public A<int>
{
};

class C : public A<bool>
{
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;

    b.foo(); // This calls ba<int>()
    c.foo(); // This calls ba<bool>()

    return 0;
}
```

It might be good to spend some time reviewing how templates and inheritance work.

[Inheritance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm)

[Templates](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm)